# Pandas is replacing rows with FALSE and TRUE with False and True

Tags: python, pandas

using pd.read_csv("my.csv"), I have certain rows that appear as either TRUE or FALSE. read_csv is changing these rows in the dataframe as "True" and "False".  Is there any way to keep case sensitivity when reading a CSV for true and false values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the dtype for the columns with TRUE and FALSE in them to equal "str" then I believe it should solve your problem.

For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", dtype=str)
```

You'll need to use a dictionary if you want other columns to be converted into specific types however.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output dataframe of `read_csv` already convert the columns to boolean values. You can verify it by calling `df.info()`. If you want to keep the columns as string values you need to pass a dict to the `dtype` parameter to specify it explicitly.